# Drag and drop between different views of a heterogeneous data hierarchy

Tags: qt, design-patterns, model-view-controller, user-interface, hierarchy

I have a hierarchical data structure that is to be visualized in several Qt views (or widgets). The data hierarchy consists of heterogeneous element types, like:

```
House
 |- Floor
 |   |- Room
 |   |   |- Window
 |   |   |- ...
 |   |- Room
 |   |   |- ...
 |- ...
```

All elements (House, Floor, Room, ...) have attributes that can be displayed. Note that this is a simplified example. The hierarchy is drawn by various views. E.g. just the identifier of a room in a list for templates (QListView/Widget), a custom view (hierarchy of QWidget subclasses for each element), a detailed view to edit the properties of e.g. a floor (QWidget subclass or QWizard).

It is also possible to drag and drop elements between several instances. E.g. moving rooms to different floors. It is possible to declare a specific floor as a template and to drag a floor from the template list in e.g. the custom view (where a house is composed).

Qt uses the [Model/View architecture](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html) to separate the data, model, and view. Because I have totally different types of views, I assume that for each view a corresponding model is required. In the case of my custom hierarchy view, each element has its own visualization, and therefore the hierarchy exists (but should not exist) three times: the data hierarchy, the model hierarchy, and the view hierarchy. This gets really messy, because every hierarchy has to be updated, if an element is dragged and dropped, removed, or copied. A better approach would be the [Presentation-Abstraction-Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation%E2%80%93abstraction%E2%80%93control) pattern. However, PAC is not applicable, since the parent of a QWidget has to be set, to embed children in their parent view. Therefore, the QWidget cannot reference an agent that is responsible for modeling the hierarchy.

It seems to me that Qt is very good in representing lists, tables, and trees of homogeneous data types (like strings). In my case, every element has an individual set of attributes that can not simply be expressed in the form of a table. In this [discussion](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/15462) it is discouraged to force a square peg into a round hole. Meaning, not to force any design in a table representation.

The core of my problem is to unite the following features in one design concept: Visualization of hierarchical data with different levels of detail. Supporting drag and drop between views, which copies the data and generates appropriate Model/View components. Supporting drag and drop in a view, which effects the data, model, and view hierarchy (which I would like to avoid implementing three times). I cannot provide one model for a house with all it subcomponents, since floors and rooms are too complex. I find it clumsy to manage three (or more) hierarchies for one drag and drop, delete, or copy action.

Is there a best practice, a design pattern, or maybe a different approach to my problem? Is this problem solvable with Qt?

I am thankful for every suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue for a while with my hierarchical structure. Everything in Qt's model-view-delegate architecture hinges on how you organize your data and how complex you're willing to get. For very simple applications, it makes sense to implement things from an item-based approach, editing item display at the View level. This gets very messy very fast.

Sounds like you're willing to get pretty complex, so I'd recommend taking a model-based approach. You can control nearly everything at the model level, including some basic display elements, data organization, and (most importantly) heirarchies.

I found it helpful when getting started to have my objects inherit [QStandardItem](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qstandarditem.html) and subclassing [QStandardItemModel](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html), since `QStandardItem` already had the parent-child hierarchy and indexing set up for me. I like incrementing `Qt::UserRole` and assigning an `enum` value to each of my custom data types. For example:

```
enum FloorProperties
{
    DAT_CARPETING = Qt::UserRole +100,
    DAT_AREA = Qt::UserRole +101,
    DAT_FLOORNUM = Qt::UserRole +102
}
```

Even if you don't want to associate a stored value with every data role (using the convenient [QStandardItem::setData()](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qstandarditem.html#setData)), you can customize [QStandardItemModel::data()](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#data) to return a computed value, stored value, whatever. Customizing *the model* allows you to think about each item as an *object*, rather than a single cell in the table/list.

The standard views should give you most of what you need on a general basis. Customize display for certain data types (Floors, Windows, integers, strings, etc) using delegates. Hope that makes some sense.

Comment: I missed the fact that QStandardItem unlike QObject can be cloned. Exploiting the UserRole seems very "Qty", too. I have to think your suggestion through, but for now it seems to be, what I am looking for. I will come back to you.